# Weird error msg when using JS.call?

Tags: javascript

While debugging I became confused at my error. I'm using firefox+firebug

When executing this code [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59PPv/1/) I get the error

```
TypeError: myranges.call(...) is undefined
```

Code:

```
var myranges = function(d){
  //return [5,8];
  return d.undefmember;
};

myranges.call(this, 1, 2).slice();
```

This confused me. When I do a proper return value [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59PPv/) I get no issues with that line (what!?!).

Ok so it returns undefined. So shouldn't I get this better error message?

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties
```

Which happens in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59PPv/4/)

I'm mostly confused at either why i got that message or what does it really mean. I thought it had a problem calling the function or myranges was bad

Comment: In Chrome I always get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined "

Comment: You're trying to execute an array method (`slice`) on `undefined` (`d.undefmember`).

Comment: @jbabey: I think he is asking why it mentions call rather then slice. At least i think he is when he brought up the alternative `undefined has no properties` message

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with firebug, because [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59PPv/6/) gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` right from the JS